# Error while installing wine at the termination with apt

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, wine, dependencies

I was trying to install wine in my system but I removed it and installed it again because I had too much files and directories ant then I got this error when I install it using apt.

```
ninjmango@lenovothinkpadt400:~$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 winehq-stable : Depends: wine-stable (= 8.0.0.0~focal-1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
ninjmango@lenovothinkpadt400:~$
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? This might have to do with the installation candidate of all packages. Thank you for your support.
:)

Comment: (Note that this is related to "Unable to correct problems, you've held broken packages. So anyone can relate to this question.)

Comment: Just install `wine` instead of `winehq-stable`.  The version from WineHQ isn't complete for install into Ubuntu well right now.

Comment: The upstream Wine documentation insists upon using their upstream Wine rather than the tested and compatible slightly-older version in the Ubuntu repositories. Unfortunately, this seems to have misled you to install incompatible packages. You are not the first; this is a common question. You should let the upstream Wine community know that their instructions broke your system.

Comment: That doesn't look like it could possibly be the full output of the command. It should say something akin to "but VERSION is to be installed" or "but will not be installed" at the end of the line with "Depends: wine-stable" in it. Also, we currently don't know what version of Ubuntu you're using. If you could specify your Ubuntu version and include the full output of "sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable" that would be helpful.